# Bijective function from $[a, b)$ to $(a, b)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

Can I get some example of bijective function from semi open set $[a, b)$ to open set $(a, b)$? I need this function to prove that $[a, b)$ and $(a, b)$ have same cardinality.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Can you come up with any example of a bijection $X \simeq X \cup \{y\}$, where $y \notin X$? How can you modify the idea of that bijection to fit your circumstance?

Comment: Check out Schröder-Bernstein Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding a bijective Map](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177871/finding-a-bijective-map) It's actually one of the related questions stackexchange suggests you look at.

Comment: Well, you need some value to map $a$ to.  So map it some point called $a_1\in(a,b)$. But then you have to map $a_1$ somewhere.  So map it to some point $a_2\in (a,b)$. Now you have to map $a_2$ to somewhere.... come up with some way to make an infinite chain of of $a\to a_1; a_1\to a_2; a_2\to a_3; etc.$  And then for all the points not on the chain just map them to themselves.  (Google for brain teasers about Infinite hotels and making room for guests; they my give you some ideas).

Answer (score -1):

To do this requires that you know some topology of the real numbers on $(0,1)$. In particular, you need to know about the enumeration of the *rational numbers* in this particular open interval. Thus let $\{q_1,q_2,...q_k,...\}$ be such an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1)$. Then define the function $f: (0,1) \to [0,1)$ as follows: $f(q_1) = 0, f(q_2) = q_1, ..., f(q_m) = q_{m-1},...$ and $f(p)= p$ for $p \in (0,1)\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Check that $f$ is a bijection.